# Adding a validator to a field type in WFFM does not work in 8.2

Tags: wffm, validation

I need to add some custom validations for my form fields, beyond what can be done by regexes. I have created a custom validator using [this approach](https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/82/working_with_actions_and_validations/validations/walkthrough_create_and_assign_a_custom_fieldtype_validator), assigned it to the built-in Single-Line Text field type, but the form did not display any validation messages (the handler is setting `args.IsValid = false` at all times for the testing purpose).

Thinking that something might be wrong with the custom implementation, I've tried to add the built-in "Email" validator to the Single-Line Text field, but nothing happened as well.

Just in case, I've republished the whole WFFM item and tested again to the same results.

Did anyone attempt to do the same? Anything I might have missed?

Comment: I have no issues with Sitecore 8.2 and WFFM validation. Have you tried same steps on vanilla Sitecore 8.2?

Comment: @MarekMusielak not yet, will have a try. Just to confirm, by "WFFM validation", you meant adding validators to field types, right?

Comment: Yes, like `the built-in "Email" validator`. If this doesn't work for you, don't try to add custom validator. First make sure that Sitecore OOTB validation works.

Comment: if you removed your custom logic and files does the validation works? , is there any JS file failing to load?

Comment: @MarekMusielak tried with a new sitecore instance on the same machine—same result.